# Request focus while dragging from windows

Tags: java, javafx, eventhandler

I'm new to JavaFX and what I need is to detect the mouse position when the user is dragging some file from outside my application, like his OS. I added a listener for dragEntered and dragExited, like this:

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseMoved = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        logger.severe(event.getScreenX() + " : " + event.getScreenY());
    }
};

scrollPane.setOnDragEntered(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
        scrollPane.getScene().getWindow().requestFocus();
        scrollPane.requestFocus();
        event.consume();
        isDragging = true;
        logger.severe(event.getScreenX() + " : " + event.getScreenY());
        scrollPane.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, mouseMoved);
    }
});

scrollPane.setOnDragExited(new EventHandler<Event>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Event event) {
        isDragging = false;
        event.consume();
        scrollPane.removeEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, mouseMoved);
    }
});

scrollPane.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<Event>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Event event) {
        isDragging = false;
        event.consume();
        scrollPane.removeEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, mouseMoved);
    }
});
```

which successfully detects that the user entered my view, dragging something, but since the user clicked outside my application, my Node doesn't have focus and I can't requestFocus either, since the focus is on the OS - so I can't add a MouseEventHandler on my scrollPane Node to detect mouse move. I need this to implement smart scrolling, so when the user is dragging on my ScrollPane, he can move the mouse at the bottom of the Node and it will scroll smoothly down.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Not tested, but does it help to request focus on the window first, i.e. do `scrollPane.getScene().getWindow().requestFocus()` before calling `scrollPane.requestFocus()`?

Comment: Thank you for you answer. This indeed changes the focus on my application (I see on my taskbar), but still, the eventhandler for the MOUSE_MOVED does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help I received from @James_D, I managed to get the mouse position at any movement, using setOnDragOver. If anyone has the same problem, here is how my code looks now:

```
scrollPane.setOnDragEntered(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
    scrollPane.getScene().getWindow().requestFocus();
    scrollPane.requestFocus();
    event.consume();
    isDragging = true;

    }
});

scrollPane.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
    double windowHeight = scrollPane.getHeight();
    double topBar = (20*windowHeight)/100;
    double bottomBar = windowHeight - topBar;
    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.LINK);
    if(event.getY() > 0 && event.getY() < topBar && scrollPane.getVvalue() > 0)
    scrollPane.setVvalue(scrollPane.getVvalue()-0.001);
    else if(event.getY() < windowHeight && event.getY() > bottomBar && scrollPane.getVvalue() < 1)
    scrollPane.setVvalue(scrollPane.getVvalue()+0.001);
    }

});

scrollPane.setOnDragExited(new EventHandler<Event>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Event event) {
    isDragging = false;
    event.consume();
    }
});

scrollPane.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<Event>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Event event) {
    isDragging = false;
    event.consume();
    }
});
```

And this provides a smart scrolling, while dragging, which means that if you drag a file from OS (for example) into the application on a scrollPane, if you move the mouse on the bottom 20% of the mentioned scrollPane, it will slowly scroll down and same if you move the mouse on the top 20% of the scrollPane - it scrolls up.

Thank you for your help and if you have any other remarks, I would love to read them.

Answer (score 0):

Use DragEvent instead of Event, for example:

```
scrollPane.setOnDragExited(new EventHandler<Event>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            event.consume();
            event.getScreenX(); // To get x position
            event.getScreenY(); // To get y position
            mouseOnTemplateBasker = false;
            logger.severe("Exited dragging something");

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, now I can get the X/Y position of the mouse but only when he leaves my view. I need some eventHandler for when the user is moving the mouse - while dragging - over my scrollPane.